# Converting XML SpreadSheet to XLSX using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, type-conversion, xlsx, xml-spreadsheet

I need to convert a XML SpreadSheet to a native Excel file (XLSX), without using MSOffice.
In particular I need to make this conversion using Javascript.

I'm searching for in "StackOverflow" web page and also in google and other portals, but I don't find nothing about it.

The XML SpreadSheet sample file is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr0Gl.png)

On the other hand, I've discovered the "excelcnv.exe" command for conversion between formats, included in MSOffice Excel installation, but just I got to convert from XLS to XLSX, but not from XML SpreadSheet to XLSX...In fact I haven't found any documentation about this "excelcnv.exe" command so I don't know if it is possible this conversion.

Also I've found about some javascript libraries like oxml.js or XLSX but I think this libraries allow create a native excel file from scratch, not convert from input files in XML SpreadSheet format.

Maybe anybody could know how do this using javascript or some javascript library.
Any help will be very welcome :)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a query, really. I would like to know if anyone has ever faced this need, or if anyone could give me some guidance on how to meet this need. As I mentioned in the original post, I have found several libraries related to creating from scratch a native excel in javascript, but nothing related to converting from an XML-Spreadsheet format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file extension. From xml to xls.
Then excelcnv will convert correctly.

```
excelcnv.exe -oice <INPUT> <OUPUT>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).